# What does “5339 之（代） 5340 之（助）” mean in the lists of characters for the new HSK 2021?

Tags: hsk

I have downloaded the last lists for new HSK, and there is somethig that i do not understand :

in upper levels HSK 7, 8, 9  the character 之 is presented like that : 5339 之（代） 5340 之（助）!

I do not see what is the link between 之 and the other characters between brackets

Anyone to help  ?

Answer (score 5):

Possibly there is a distinction between a 代名詞 (pronoun) vs. 助詞 (particle). The 3rd person pronoun usage of 之 and ordinary relational connector 之 might be sufficiently different to be considered separate.

There might be a separate entry for 之 (動) for 動詞: the verb 'to go', also a meaning of 之.

Comment: Also see https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/43618/%e4%b9%8b-grammar-and-usage

Comment: Thanks, there is no entry for 動 for that hanzi, but there are a few entries for 动 for other characters.  So this will be clarified for me, when i find a hanzi with another character between brackets    :-)